# Нужен файл со словами и их переводами

Tags: база-данных, словари

Здравствуйте, нужен файл для того, чтобы составить базу данных словаря (англо-русского). Если у кого есть, буду признателен, если вы поделитесь. Либо подскажите, где можно что-то найти по этому поводу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Англо-русский словарь Мюллера http://mexalib.com/view/8483

Вот еще он же, но в других форматах и редакции http://mueller-dic.chat.ru/

**Обновление**

```
Begin - начало;
Hello - привет;
World - мир;
End - конец;
```

Сообщите, сколько слов вам надо и с какой целью?

Если хотите делать полноценный переводчик, то придумайте, как парсить словарь. Поищите в инете, возможно он есть в формате SQL или типа БД MSAccess или в формате, который вы сможете преобразовать в необходимый вам.

Comment: Спасибо, но, увы, его (как мне кажется) будет сложно парсить. 
Может быть, вы знаете про какой-то более "скупой" словарь,где хранятся слова в виде "слово-перевод(ы)" (что было бы идеально) или близкие к такому?

Comment: Обновил ответ